# How do I create a profile in PowerShell 7.3.2?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-11, powershell-core

I am unable to create a profile in **PowerShell 7.3.2**.

When I run `notepad $PROFILE`, the notepad prompts to create this **Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1** nonexistent file yet I see no file with this name in `C:\Users\1999q\Documents\PowerShell`.

When I run `New-Item -Path $PROFILE -Type File -Force` OR `New-Item $PROFILE.CurrentUserCurrentHost` OR

```
if (!(Test-Path -Path $PROFILE)) {
  New-Item -ItemType File -Path $PROFILE -Force
}
```

I get the error `New-Item: Could not find file 'C:\Users\1999q\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'.`.

Moreover, `Test-Path $PROFILE` gives me **False**.

However, `$PROFILE | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty | Format-List` displays the following:

```
TypeName   : System.String
Name       : AllUsersAllHosts
MemberType : NoteProperty
Definition : string AllUsersAllHosts=C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\profile.ps1

TypeName   : System.String
Name       : AllUsersCurrentHost
MemberType : NoteProperty
Definition : string AllUsersCurrentHost=C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

TypeName   : System.String
Name       : CurrentUserAllHosts
MemberType : NoteProperty
Definition : string CurrentUserAllHosts=C:\Users\1999q\Documents\PowerShell\profile.ps1

TypeName   : System.String
Name       : CurrentUserCurrentHost
MemberType : NoteProperty
Definition : string CurrentUserCurrentHost=C:\Users\1999q\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

I am unable to comprehend what exactly is going on, can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you remember to save the file? FWIW the `$PROFILE` path strings exist regardless of whether the file exists on disk or not, there's nothing weird or wrong in the files not existing on disk

Comment: When I edit the file with `notepad $PROFILE` and try to "save" or "save as", it says file not found for Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1.

Comment: `New-Item -ItemType File -Path $PROFILE -Force` should work. If it doesn't, there could be a permission issue. Check permissions of the parent folder.

Comment: Everything is check except for special permissions .

Comment: Thanks! The issue's resolved. I am able to save the file if I run notepad / vscode as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to attempt

1. Run in admin shell

   - `notepad $Profile`
2. If fails, in admin shell

   - `New-Item -ItemType File -Path $PROFILE -Force`
   - `notepad $Profile`
3. If fails (unlikely) still in admin shell

   - `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`
   - Go to step 1